# ¿Cómo haría para sacar datos de dentro de un array JSON en java?

Tags: java, json, api, jsonarray

En este `json`, me gustaría conseguir sacar de `results`, del id `PC` todos los games:
https://api.rawg.io/api/platforms?key=bf61e2970a4d4af8b77dac08fbc273f4

```
{
   "count":51,
   "next":"https://api.rawg.io/api/platforms?key=bf61e2970a4d4af8b77dac08fbc273f4&page=2",
   "previous":null,
   "results":[
      {
         "id":4,
         "name":"PC",
         "slug":"pc",
         "games_count":446263,
         "image_background":"https://media.rawg.io/media/games/588/588c6bdff3d4baf66ec36b1c05b793bf.jpg",
         "image":null,
         "year_start":null,
         "year_end":null,
         "games":[
            {
               "id":3498,
               "slug":"grand-theft-auto-v",
               "name":"Grand Theft Auto V",
               "added":17407
            },
            {
               "id":3328,
               "slug":"the-witcher-3-wild-hunt",
               "name":"The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt",
               "added":16143
            },
            {
               "id":4200,
               "slug":"portal-2",
               "name":"Portal 2",
               "added":15229
            },
            {
               "id":5286,
               "slug":"tomb-raider",
               "name":"Tomb Raider (2013)",
               "added":13629
            },
            {
               "id":5679,
               "slug":"the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim",
               "name":"The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim",
               "added":13210
            },
            {
               "id":4291,
               "slug":"counter-strike-global-offensive",
               "name":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive",
               "added":13119
            }
         ]
      }
  }
```

EDIT(Este seria el codigo que estoy intentando utilizar, pero me da error en el JSONObject["object"]):

```
JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("https://api.rawg.io/api/platforms?key=bf61e2970a4d4af8b77dac08fbc273f4"); 

        JSONObject jsonobject1 = json.getJSONObject("object");
//      JSONObject jsresults = jsonobject.getJSONObject("results");
//      JSONObject js0 = jsresults.getJSONObject("0");
//      JSONObject jsgames = js0.getJSONObject("games");
//      System.out.println(jsgames.get("name"));

        JSONArray arr = jsonobject1.getJSONArray("results");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
            String post_id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("0");
            System.out.println(post_id);
        }
```

Comment: y como lo has intentado, muestranos tu codigo para poder ayudarte....

Comment: Publica en la pregunta el fragmento de código al que te refieres y un poco de contexto, así como la salida esperada.

Comment: Acabo de poner el código que estoy utilizando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el nombre de los games:

```
JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("https://api.rawg.io/api/platforms?key=bf61e2970a4d4af8b77dac08fbc273f4");        
        //convert json results to array
        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("results");
        //from jsonArray name PC get games names
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        //get games names
        JSONArray jsonArray2 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("games");
        //iterate over jsonArray2 and print names
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray2.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(jsonArray2.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
        }
```

Para ver las consolas y sus juegos:

```
JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("https://api.rawg.io/api/platforms?key=bf61e2970a4d4af8b77dac08fbc273f4");        
        //convert json results to array
        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("results");
        //iterate over array
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("name"));
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);    
            JSONArray jsonArray2 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("games");
            //iterate over jsonArray2 and print names
            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray2.length(); j++) {
                System.out.println("---"+jsonArray2.getJSONObject(j).getString("name"));
            }        
        }
```

Comment: Vale, otra cosita, si quisiera que saliera el `name` y también la consola a la que pertenece cada juego, en este caso `PC`, ¿Cómo podría hacer para que aparecieran ambos datos?

Comment: Vale, al final lo conseguí, era simplemente añadir dentro del for lo siguiente: `System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("name"));`

Comment: Hay que ver la estructura de tu JSON y sus niveles, te puse un ejemplo iterando todas las consolas y sus juegos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener los juegos de PC, de manera simple usando una combinación de `getJSONArray` y `getJSONObject` dependiendo del tipo de objeto que sea la clave en el json. Finalmente puedes iterar los juegos de PC con un simple `for`:

```
JSONArray gamesPC = json.getJSONArray( "results" )
        .getJSONObject( 0 )
        .getJSONArray( "games" );

for (int i = 0; i < gamesPC.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject game = gamesPC.getJSONObject( i );
    System.out.println(game.toString(4));
    
    // Alternativamente usa esto para imprimir solo el nombre  
    System.out.println(game.getString("name"));
}
```

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, y si quisiera sacar 1 solo dato de dentro de game, por ejemplo el nombre?

Comment: @jolugara dentro del `for` después de `game` simplemente usas `String name = game.getString( "name" )`. Te lo agregué en el código.